# Does a using `.exists()` on a queryset with `.annotate()` runs the annotations?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

So, I have this queryset where I run pretty heavy annotations , but I need to also check whether any data exists or not. So if I run exists() would the annotations be evaluated too?

Comment: it will try to yes, as you can also filter by annotations which would have an impact on your `exists()` result. PS you can always just check the generated SQL in django and most other ORMs